# How did the Dugs kill the Zillo Beast previously?

Tags: star-wars

When the [Zillo Beast](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Zillo_Beast) was awoken on Malastare during the clone wars, one of the [Dugs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dug) said to [Mace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mace_Windu) and [Anakin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker) "our fuel is deadly to the beasts. It killed them in the past, it will kill this one now". But how exactly did they kill them in the past because the way they tried in the clone wars didn't work?
[image: The Malastarian Zillo Beast]

Comment: One assumes that they had more of it, and were able to administer larger amounts of it over a longer period.